# Dynamic SQL with table name from a field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Is there a way to generate dynamic sql statement, such that the field value from one table participates in a table name being joined?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
DECLARE @MainProc NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'dbo.MainProc'

SET @sql += N'SELECT ref.*
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (' + @MainProc + N', ''OBJECT'') AS ref
INNER JOIN ' + ref.referenced_database_name + '.sys.objects AS o ON ref.referenced_id = o.object_id AND o.type = ''P''
WHERE ref.referenced_schema_name NOT IN (''system'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

How can the value of **ref.referenced_database_name** be attached to **sys.objects**?

Comment: And would do you expect if there are many `referenced_database_name`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with a little refactoring.  In your original example you were trying to extract a value from `dm_sql_referenced_entities` before you had queried it.

```
DECLARE @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
DECLARE @MainProc   NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Fact.Account_Load'

/* Builds the sys.Objects query.
 * Can return multiple queries.
 */
SELECT      
    @sql += 
    '
        SELECT
            s.*
        FROM
            ' + QUOTENAME(ref.referenced_database_name) + '.sys.objects AS s
        WHERE
            s.Object_Id = ' + CAST(ref.referenced_id AS VARCHAR(255)) + '
            AND s.Type = ''P''
        ;
    '
FROM
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('Fact.Account_Load', 'OBJECT') AS ref
WHERE
    ref.referenced_database_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    ref.referenced_database_name,
    ref.referenced_id
;

-- Executes dynamic query.
EXECUTE(@sql);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me a lot, now I get the general idea of how to construct such kind of queries